# Darwin `ld` stubbornly won't find symbol that's defined in object file, while `lld` does

Tags: macos, ld, darwin, mach-o, lld

When using macOS's built in `ld`, I get the following error:

```
ld -arch x86_64 -platform_version macos 11.0 12.2.1 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk -lSystem -lc++ -o /Users/blashyrk/Documents/source/nim/asserttrigger /Users/blashyrk/.cache/nim/asserttrigger_d/asserttrigger.o 

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_nlvmEHPersonality", referenced from:
  Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in asserttrigger.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

However, that symbol is a function that's defined inside that very same object file.
Using `objdump` on the object file, I can confirm that the function is indeed there:

```
objdump -t ~/.cache/nim/asserttrigger_d/asserttrigger.o | grep nlvmEH
00000000000063b0 l     F __TEXT,__text _nlvmEHPersonality
```

And just to make sure I wasn't crazy, I decided to see for myself with Ghidra (please see attached image).

So my question is, what makes macOS's `ld` not find this symbol? When using LLVM's `lld` it works, so the symbol is defined properly.

Am I, perhaps, missing a flag? Is `ld` expecting the EH personality function to be a part of some external object/library?

Here's also a link to the object file, if someone wants to try it out on their end: https://www46.zippyshare.com/v/0UFxM7zD/file.html

The program (if you manage to link it successfully) should run and exit with no output.

[image: Ghidra output]

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten it to work by changing the linkage type of `nlvmEHPersonality` from internal to external.

For some reason, `ld64` cant't find it with internal linkage even though `lld` can.